# Definition Resolution

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

[image]

Your final answer(s) should be thematic.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To start,

> the word `perimeter` is there... and it's a "definition" for the word `rim`, which is inside it. Surely, that must be relevant?
>
>  And if you line up the red frame, you can see it perfectly covers the word "rim".
>  [image]
>
>  The word "limit", though... it doesn't have a nice substring that it defines. But it *is* written strangely...
>
>  [image]
>  ...and if we look carefully, we can see the word CAP!

So, now to continue this with the rest!

It starts to get trickier from here:

> [image]
>  PAL is written upside-down...
>
>  ...and HIP and ROYAL are written sideways.
>
>  [image]

And some even weirder things happen...

> The next two are entirely based on the font's design, not really using the individual letters:
>  [image]
>
>  ...the next one is in *whitespace*...
>  [image]
>
>  ... and the last one is in hanzi! Online translators give "thermal" for `熱的`, and indeed we can find HOT inside it.
>  [image]

Great!

...now what?

> Let's try filling things into the bottom part! Based off of ROYAL and HIP, it looks like we should rotate all of these before entering them:
>  [image]

And now...

> we can do it again, and get
>  [image]
>  **MACROPHOTOGRAPHY**!

But there's still one more thing:

> the bottom row tells us we can do the same thing *yet again*. And this gives us the final answer to the puzzle, **CROP**:
>
>  [image]
>
>  a perfect description of what we've done to solve this puzzle!

Comment: This is a brilliant solve of a brilliant puzzle. +1

Comment: This is so great, even just reading it feels satisfying.